# Maintain indenting like in an IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, auto-indent

Now that I know how to highlight syntax in `EditText`, I would like to as how I can maintain auto-indenting like `Notepad++` or `Eclipse`. For eg:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        System.out.println("Hello, again!");
    }
}
```

How do IDEs know how much space to add such that my second `System.out.println()` is right underneath the first ?

Comment: Please state what is unclear here so that I can add more info :)

Comment: Code editors simply keep a count of the number of tabs to indent by (or spaces or other characters depending on options).  They simply increment that number when entering a new block, most commonly the opening brace in Java but also case statements and some other constructs, then decrement the count when the enclosing block is closed.  Something like `if (currentChar.equals(openBrace) && endOfLine){tabCount++;}`

Comment: @Simon If you can elaborate more and give a simple non-code example then I will accept your answer

Comment: There's not much to elaborate really.  You start with no tabs at the first line.  Let's just use opening braces for ease.  Every time you find an opening brace, which is not a character withing a string, add one to the tab count.  Every time you find a closing brace, subtract one from the tab count.  When you print a line to the output, you add however many tabs are required at the beginning.

Comment: In Eclipse Preferences you can look at Java / Code Style / Formatter to see all the rules that are used  by the Eclipse formatter.

Answer (score -2):

Eclipse can auto-indent on demand. To do this, select a desired code piece, then press Ctrl+I ("Fix indentation").

Comment: This does not answer the question.